# Strange host on connect attempt

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The code is:

```
$mysql = new mysqli('10.1.36.20', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
```

The result is:
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'10.1.36.111' (using password: YES) in ....

webserver IP: 10.1.36.13;
mysql server IP: 10.1.36.20

where did it got 10.1.36.111?

I was tried through mysql_connect - The same problem.

Comment: a proxy of some sort, maybe?

Comment: Perhaps your web server has more than one IP address assigned to it.

Comment: It is your network IP from which you are making a request to the MySQL server.

Comment: Try printing $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] in your php page to confirm the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

The **fastest** fix is to look at the error and read it. For example, if "(using password: NO)", then you need to make sure your connection is using a password.
If "(using password: YES)", then make sure you are using the correct password.

If the error reports

Couldn't connect :
          localhost: Connection error to server 'localhost' with user 'username_user'

Make sure you have added the user to the database and granted permissions to this user. 
or 
Create a new **user** or use proper **username** and **password** for the database

for managing this go to your Phpmyadmin->User->Add user

**Default:**
username:"root"
password:""
 And use this function for reference.

```
<?php

// db connect to nm database
function db_connect_nm()
{
  //Database server
    $host= 'localhost';
    $nm_name= 'myname_databasename'; 
    $nm_user= 'myname_dbusername';
    $nm_pword= 'password';

   $nm_connect = new mysqli($host, $nm_user, $nm_pword, $nm_name);

   if (!$nm_connect)
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to NM database ');
   else
     return $nm_connect; 
}

?>
```

9 out of 10 PHP problems can be resolved by **setting** so please check that too

Comment: pma is not serious. Only console! Only hardcore!
Have you read the question? I understand the mysql_connect answer. There is unknown host. I pass another IP address and asking why connection refused from another IP addres.

Comment: is it working good in localhost ? if yes, please check 1) redirection settings 2) db connect file 3) check server ip and user profile of my sql.

Comment: @vivin You have completely missed the point. Read the question again.